# Secret chat session in python telethon

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, chatbot, telethon

How can i start a secret chat session using telethon? I've found a solution on the web; https://pypi.org/project/telethon-secret-chat/, but i'm not sure how it is supposed to work. I understand all the other stuff but what is supposed to go inside in the `manager.start_secret_chat(target)` function?

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon_secret_chat import SecretChatManager

client = TelegramClient('log', app_id, app_hash)

async def replier(event):
    # all events are encrypted by default
    if event.decrypted_event.message and event.decrypted_event.message == "hello":
        await event.reply("**hi**") # parse_mode is markdown by default


async def new_chat(chat, created_by_me):
    if created_by_me:
        print("User {} has accepted our secret chat request".format(chat))
    else:
        print("We have accepted the secret chat request of {}".format(chat))


manager = SecretChatManager(client, auto_accept=True,
                            new_chat_created=new_chat)  # automatically accept new secret chats
manager.add_secret_event_handler(func=replier)  # we can specify the type of the event

with client:
    client.run_until_disconnected()

manager.start_secret_chat(target)
```

Comment: Hi. Please remove the `python-telegram-bot` tag, as that's for a different library.

Comment: @CallMeStag done

Answer (score 0):

Target can be the user_id. See this example:

```
# wait for incoming message
@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def incoming_message_handler(event):
  userId = event.original_update.user_id

  # start secret chat
  await manager.start_secret_chat(userId)
```